# Specifying the style of edges in directed graphs

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

How do I specify the style of individual edges in a directed graph (in Mathematica version 9)?

Consider maybe this

```
Graph[{"ftr1" -> "ftr2", "ftr2" -> "ftr3", "ftr3" -> "ftr4"}]
```

How can I change the color and make dashed the individual edges in any manner that I'd like?  It seems like

```
Graph[{"ftr1" -> "ftr2", "ftr2" -> "ftr3", "ftr3" -> "ftr4"}, EdgeStyle -> {"ftr1" -> "ftr2" -> Black, "ftr2" -> "ftr3" -> Blue, "ftr3" -> "ftr4" -> Green}]
```

Fails for directed graphs, but works for undirected graphs

```
Graph[{"ftr1" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr2", "ftr2" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr3", "ftr3" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr4"}, EdgeStyle -> {"ftr1" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr2" -> Black, "ftr2" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr3" -> Blue, "ftr3" \[UndirectedEdge] "ftr4" -> Green}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [halmir commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71391/specifying-the-style-of-edges-in-directed-graphs/71402#comment195759_71402) the documentation of [`EdgeStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeStyle.html) notes the following *possible issue*:

> [image]

---

Thus you should use `\[DirectedEdge]`:

```
Graph[
  {"ftr1" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr2", 
   "ftr2" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr3", 
   "ftr3" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr4"}, 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  {"ftr1" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr2" -> Black, 
   "ftr2" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr3" -> Blue, 
   "ftr3" \[DirectedEdge] "ftr4" -> Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Not a bug. It's documented (under possible issue in EdgeStyle documentation).

Comment: @halmir Thank you, edited the answer :)